# Get all XML nodes that contain a certain inner node in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath

I am receiving a XML string information for many tables. The problem is that in stead of having the format

```
<root>
  <Candy>
    <Name>M-M</Name>
    <Size>Small</Size>
  </Candy>
  <Candy>
    <Name>KitKat</Name>
    <Size>Medium</Size>
  </Candy>
  <Fruit>
    <Description>Banana</Description>
    <Color>Yellow</Color>
  </Fruit>
  <Fruit>
    <Description>Cherry</Description>
    <Color>Red</Color>
  </Fruit>
<root>
```

What I get is

```
<root>
  <Candy>
    <M-M>
      <Size>Small</Size>
    </M-M>
    <KitKat>
      <Size>Medium</Size>
    <KitKat>
  </Candy>
  <Fruit>
    <Banana>
      <Color>Yellow</Color>
    </Banana>
    <Cherry>
      <Color>Red</Color>
    </Cherry>
  </Fruit>
</root>
```

I need to insert the rows for candy in the table Candy and the rows for fruits in the table Fruit. If I received the first format I'd just do

```
 select *
   from
openxml (@hDoc, '/root/Candy', 2)
```

and I'd get all the Candy rows, but the guys from the other side of the web service are reluctant to send it that way. So, before I put a fight, is there a way to get all Candy using the second xml format? like requesting all nodes that have an inner node named Size? I'm using SQLServer 2008 so I can use either the openxml instruction or the newer node functions, which I haven't learned how to use yet. Also, process speed is more important than memory, I think...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
declare @T xml = '<root>
  <Candy>
    <M-M>
      <Size>Small</Size>
    </M-M>
    <KitKat>
      <Size>Medium</Size>
    </KitKat>
  </Candy>
  <Fruit>
    <Banana>
      <Color>Yellow</Color>
    </Banana>
    <Cherry>
      <Color>Red</Color>
    </Cherry>
  </Fruit>
</root>'

select candies.X.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)') as Name
       , candies.X.value('Size[1]', 'varchar(100)') as Size
from @T.nodes('root/Candy/*[Size]') as candies(X)
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/4901)**

The xpath `root/Candy/*[Size]` means get all child nodes of `<Candy>`, whatever it's name, having child `<Size>`.